# Can I use the cancel command in MSE?

Tags: support, mathjax

I was typing an answer to a question here in MSE and since I did not want to write with words that the integral cancels to zero, I tried to use the command `\cancel`. However this did not work. Cancel is marked in red . This message is produced by the error extension of MathJaX. I also tried the command: `\require{cancel}` . Unfortunately the same result showed up here. This time it was not highlighted in red but a framebox appeared around the equation. Obvisoubly the equation did not rended.

So, my question is: Can we use  the command `\cancel` here in MSE? (if so, HOW?) I think that it would make our posts more rigorous and of course we would not be forced to write more words when a cancel command is just fine to do the same job.

Comment: Yes; [see this answer on the MathJax FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/13183) If you have a more specific problem please explain it.

Comment: The above being said I disagree  with posts being made more rigorous by this. I doubt this gets much usage in advanced mathematical text; I would not recall seeing this ever in a research paper. Moreover, over reliance on formulas is quite bad for searches and also for rendering. Too large formulas often break the page (especially on mobile)

Comment: @quid Thank you for the instructions. I don't use it frequently, but sometimes I do when I don't want to write down that something cancels to something.

Comment: You are welcome. Certainly sometimes this command can come in handy. Since this seems to work for you I will vote to close this as duplicate.

Comment: @quid Over reliance on the crutch of natural language often obstructs *mathematical* comprehension, which is much worse.

Comment: @BillDubuque certainly, *over* reliance on most anything is not good, essentially by definition. (My formulation was not so good there.) However, on this site I see a lot of posts (more often than not by users that seem not yet really used to writing mathematics beyond solutions to exercices) that would be improved a lot, in my opinion, with some words. The converse, too much words and too little fomulas, does also happen, but a lot less frequently.

Comment: @quid I think that as long as there is a healthy balance among the answers then all is well.

Comment: @BillDubuque I agree that different people understand different styles better, and thus I agree that a mix is good.